# Constructor Based Inheritance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, this

I have the following code:

```
        function Vector(X,Y) //Constructor
        {
            this.X = X;
            this.Y = Y;
        }

        function Box(Size /*Vector*/, Position /*Vector*/) //Constructor
        {
            this.Size = Size;
            this.Position = Position;
            this.Velocity = new Vector(0,0);
            this.Anchored = true;
            this.CanCollide = false;
            this.Colour = "rgb(50,50,50)";

            this.draw = function()
            {
                ctx.fillStyle = this.Colour;
                ctx.fillRect(this.Position.X-(this.Size.X*0.5),this.Position.Y-(this.Size.Y*0.5),this.Size.X,this.Size.Y);
            }
        }

        function Player(Size,Position)
        {
            Box(Size,Position);
            this.Anchored = false;
            this.CanCollide = true;
            this.Colour = "rgb(0,100,0)";
        }

        var Me = new Player(new Vector(25,25), new Vector(10,10));
        console.log(Me.Velocity);
```

If you look at the first statement in the constructor function, 'Player', you'll see that I called the function Box; I'm trying to inherit the properties and methods of 'Box' into 'Player'. I don't get any errors, however when I try and reference an inherited property, (the last statement), it returns undefined.

Why doesn't Player inherit Box's properties? I understand that JS is prototype based, and that this is extremely unorthodox, but I cannot make any sense as to how to inherit through multiple objects using prototypes.

Comment: Use `Box.call(this, Size, Position)`.

Comment: Thank you! One question: Why doesn't the function automatically assume the scope of 'this'?

Comment: More on inheritance, constructor functions and prototype here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not inherit the properties of `Box` that way. That is because you are calling the `Box` function on the global context and the value of `this` will point to the global object `window`. To change the value of the `this` inside the function, use `call()` or `apply()` or even `bind()`.
When you change the value of `this` this way inside the `Player` function, the initialisation code inside `Box` will be run with the instance of `Player` as its context.

```
function Player(Size,Position)
 {
   Box.call(this,Size,Position); //the this value will point to instance of Player
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another options is to set Player's prototype:

```
Player.prototype = new Box();
Player.prototype.constructor = Player;
```

Then you wouldn't call the Box constructor directly.  It would be called for you, so:

```
function Player(Size,Position)
{
    this.Size = Size;
    this.Position = Position;
    this.Anchored = false;
    this.CanCollide = true;
    this.Colour = "rgb(0,100,0)";
}
```

Comment: Better use object.create and box.call to inherit prototype and instance specific members. Now you're inheriting instance specific members on the shared prototype. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711